# jQuery accordion active: not working in Firefox using ID tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, accordion

In IE, Chrome, Safari & Opera this works:

```
<a id="VY" class="menu-title">Very Young</a>

$("#accordion").accordion({
  autoHeight: false,
  collapsible: true,
  header: '.menu-title',
  navigation: true,
  event: 'click',
  active: VY,
  animated: 'easeslide'
});
```

My accordion menu opens at the 'Very Young' link `id="VY"`

But in Firefox it doesn't, it displays the menu with all items open.
Is it possible to get Firefox to display it like the others or is there a JavaScript/jQuery method to get the index of the item with an id of e.g. 'VY' which is what enables it to open the menu at the appropriate place e.g. active: 3.

Comment: Are there any JavaScript errors on the page? Are there multiple elements with ID="VY" on the page?

Comment: No JavaScript  errors, only one id="VY"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have defined the `VY` variable previously in JavaScript but didn't post it in your example, then that's probably your problem. The accorion's [active](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion#option-active) property expects an element or selector (or a few other things--see docs for complete list). Instead of `active: VY` use:

```
$("#accordion").accordion({
  autoHeight: false,
  collapsible: true,
  header: '.menu-title',
  navigation: true,
  event: 'click',
  active: '#VY',
  animated: 'easeslide'
});
```

Comment: Thank you - no VY is not previously defined as a JavaScript variable. I have looked at the jQuery docs and found them rather minimalist in content this also applies to the forums a lot of questions without answers. The main issue for me with this, is the code works in all the top 5 browsers except for Firefox. As the menus I am using are dynamically created I do not know the index/number of a menu item but do know the ID when creating the page. I think I will have to look at obtaining the index first as a work around for Firefox.

Comment: I have just tried using 
     `active: '#VY',`
instead of
     `active: VY,`
which did the trick - Thank you